# ImportError: cannot import name 'TwitterPreprocessor' from 'preprocessor'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, twitterapi-python

I am installing the package for data-cleaning purpose,

```
!pip install tweet-preprocessor
from preprocessor import TwitterPreprocessor
```

I am using both Jupyter and Colab, there is no issue using in Jupyter. But still, receiving this issue in colab:

**ImportError: cannot import name 'TwitterPreprocessor' from 'preprocessor' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/preprocessor/**init**.py)**

Please help me with this problem to correct.

*Thank you*

Comment: If that answer helped you out, you may accept and upvote it correspondingly. Obviously, there is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The library [tweet-preprocessor](https://pypi.org/project/tweet-preprocessor/) simply doesn't have the `TwitterPreprocessor` you're trying to import. Take a look at the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/s/preprocessor/tree/master/preprocessor) - no `TwitterPreprocessor` in sight.

It's suggested to import it via: `import preprocessor as p` (or import one of the said names from the GitHub repo). You can look at the [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/s/preprocessor/blob/master/preprocessor/__init__.py) what names you're able to import.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'TwitterPreprocessor' from 'preprocessor' (*[...]*\preprocessor\_*init*_.py)